# "So" as a conjunction

Tags: grammar

I'm a teacher of English as a Foreign Language, and I would like to get some information on SO as a conjunction. As far as I know, it's a coordinating conjunction, and it's part of the FANBOYS group. I know that SO THAT is considered a subordinating conjunction. However, I've heard a fellow teacher affirming that SO can also be a subordinating conjunction depending on its meaning. Is is true? This would change the way in which we analyse and classify sentences into "simple", "compound", "complex", and "compound- complex". 
Thanks in advance,

Mary

Comment: So you may be in no doubt about your colleague's competence, I assure you that bare *so* may act as what various grammatical sects call a *subordinator* or *subordinating conjunction*.

Comment: Was the fellow teacher referring to _so_ sentences that included, but were not immediately preceding, _that_ or _as_? Because that construction sometimes occurs and is correct.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 3):

I mostly agree with your colleague, but I would quibble over the phrase "depending on its meaning". The parts of speech are a characterization of the *grammar* of a word, which does not necessarily align with its *meaning*. For example, the meaning of *so* is the same in both "He started yelling; so, I left" and "He started yelling, so I left", but in the former it is considered an adverb (modifying the independent clause "I left"), whereas in the latter it is considered a conjunction.

As for why I agree with your colleague — consider a sentence like this one:

> You mother  enrolled you in the pre-Academy program so you'd have a little direction, not so you'd have a reason to go become some half-cocked vagabond on Earth. [[link](http://books.google.com/books?id=8FpKTACtzzQC&pg=PA54&dq=%22not%20so%22)]

It's clear that *not* is modifying the second *so* clause (or, perhaps, conjoining the two *so* clauses). This implies that the *so* clauses are subordinate clauses, functioning as adverbials, rather than independent clauses standing on their own. (One would never say something like, *"You mother enrolled you in the pre-Academy program for she wanted you to have a little direction, not for she wanted you to have a reason to go become some half-cocked vagabond on Earth.")